# Risk function for vectors

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

How do apply risk functions to vectors?

Here is the problem I have encountered:

Let $X = (X_1, X_2, . . . , X_p)$ be a collection of independent random variables with $X_i \sim N(\mu_i, 1)$
for $i = 1,2,...,p$ and $\mu = (\mu_1,\mu_2,...,\mu_p) \in \mathbb{R}^p$, and $p\geq 3$.  Let $\hat\mu = X$ be the maximum likelihood estimator for $\mu$. Show that $\hat\mu$ has risk
equal to $p$ when using a quadratic loss function.

How do you apply the risk function $$R(\mu,\hat\mu) = \mathbb{E}[(\hat\mu-\mu)^2]$$ to vectors $\mu$ and $\hat\mu$ and end up with a scalar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I think there is something wrong in the statement "  $\hat{\mu} = X$ is the MLE of $\mu$  ", because [MLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood#Principles) cannot be just equal to random variable. If we want to use maximum likelihood, we have a multivariate normal distribution for $X$ with diagonal identity covariance matrix, then we can use the [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Density_function) of multivariate normal distribution in the formula of MLE (product of densities).</s>

[Multivariate normal likelihood](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~epxing/Class/10701-08s/recitation/gaussian.pdf) for $\mu$ is $\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{N}\sum x_i$ ($x_i$ are $N$ sampled vectors). So if we have *only* *one* vector $x$ in our sample, then *indeed* $MLE(\mu)=x$.

But here the actual idea is that the value $x$ of random variable $X$ is taken as the estimator ($\xi$) of the mean $\mu$:

$$\hat{\mu}=\xi_{X}(\mu) = x$$

Let $\mu = EX$ and remember that covariance matrix is $E(X-\mu) (X-\mu)^T = I$ and $\| x \|^2 = x^T x$. 
Lets compute the quadratic loss $L(\mu,\hat{\mu}) =\|\mu - \hat{\mu}\|^2 $:

$$EL(\mu,\hat{\mu}) = EL(\mu,x) = E(X-\mu)^T (X-\mu) = p$$

In the last equality note that transpose is different, so we get sum of the diagonal elements instead of identity matrix.

Comment: Thanks very much! I thought there that might be a mistake in the question but I left it in case I was wrong. :)

Comment: @user77904 Now I see: [Multivariate normal likelihood](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~epxing/Class/10701-08s/recitation/gaussian.pdf) for $\mu$ is $\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{N}\sum x_i$ ($x_i$ are $N$ sampled vectors). So if we have _only_one vector $x$ in our sample, then _indeed_ $MLE(\mu)=x$.

Comment: @user77904 I have updated my post, there is no mistake in the question.